# Migration from Magento 1.9 to 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am getting below error while migrating data from Magento 1.9 to 2.

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Invalid parameter configuration provided for $sourceDocument argument of Migration\RecordTransformer

I just saw someone were also getting same issue previously.
Did you get any solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably configured source database is Magento 2 and destination database is Magento 1 in your file config.xml. But it has to do the opposite, Magento 1 is your source and Magento 2 is your destination.

Make sure you have entered the prefix () if Magento 1 uses the prefix.